# How to perform coefficient test in linear model with robust covariance matrix?

Tags: r, regression, robust

I estimate a linear model and then calculate a (White) heteroscedasticity robust variance covariance matrix.  This allows me to do the following (where `hr.cov` is the robust covariance matrix):

```
> coeftest(model, hr.cov)

t test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 157.146959  14.760426 10.6465  8.99e-15 ***
x             0.134499   0.033050  4.0696 0.0001575 ***
d            20.921722  16.043356  1.3041 0.1978438    
x:d           0.068120   0.047416  1.4366 0.1566992    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

I would like to do a one sided test whether d<0 (as opposed to different from 0 in both directions which is what is shown above).  I would like to be able to type something like `test(model,d<0,hr.cov)`.  How should I go about this?